# What can I do about a slow shared internet connection?

Tags: internet-connection, bandwidth, shared-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet connection too slow](https://superuser.com/questions/119752/internet-connection-too-slow)

I am in a student residence, and the internet acces provided (cablecom / studentcom) is very slow.

Speedtest.net results:

```
ping (ms)  download (mbps)  upload (mbps)
112        0.2              fail
60         0.17             fail
59         0.12             fail
60         0.19             0.04
```

What can I do about that ?

---

The first and obvious thing to do is warn the society, but this has already been done.

An other possibility is to get a smartphone, and use it as an wifi acces point. But that's expansive, and most of the phone providers don't allow it.

I wonder if there are some software that can diagnose network and help troubleshooting.
I also wonder if they are software to soak up more bandwith like orbit, but for the whole browser (not just only downloads).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet connection too slow](http://superuser.com/questions/119752/internet-connection-too-slow) and/or [What tools could help me figure-out what is wrong with my internet connection?](http://superuser.com/questions/248247/what-tools-could-help-me-figure-out-what-is-wrong-with-my-internet-connection)

Answer (score 4):

If you can't upgrade your connection then you can optimize the bandwidth usage, something like an old PC can be installed as a linux proxy server/router, that can allow for:

- The proxy server (squid) will store locally frequently visit websites and images, that can reduce your bandwidth needs and gives you the effect of a fast connection.
- The router/firewall functions in Linux allows you to limit traffic in a more balanced way so the bandwidth available is distributed fairly between all users.
- If possible, you can block some services and types of traffic so the bandwidth is used on really important things.

Best regards,

Comment: Good answer. Blocking certain types of traffic, such as Netflix videos or BitTorrent files, can go a long way towards freeing up the precious bandwidth. Though it'll also go a long way towards pissing off all your dorm mates.

Comment: In your second bullet, the router/firewall has to affect all students, not just me, I guess. So I cannot set up this kind of router unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Connection must be managed. Except chaching-proxy you can think about additional HW, which can implement QoS, traffic priority, and (for same bandwidth) give interactive traffic some more freedom and speed. Anyway, find local good network-admin